# Связать button с частью изображения

Tags: css, html5

Есть тег button, его нужно связать с конкретным местом на изображении. То есть, чтобы кнопка нажималась только при нажатии на это конкретное место. Координаты укажу самостоятельно.

```
<button><p class=im"><img src="image.jpg" alt="image" height="200"></p></button>
```

Comment: Картинка отдельно, а баттон с цветом transparent и position: relative/absolute расположен над картинкой в нужных координатах

Comment: Нужно, чтобы кнопку не было видно. Не могли бы написать эту часть часть кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно расположить картинку и кнопку внутри общего контейнера. Картинка задаст размер контейнеру, а кнопка встанет на свое место через абсолютное позиционирование.

> Рабочий пример: https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/545ad43n/. Наведите на "NEW YORK".

Верстка:

```
<div class="clickable-img">
  <img src="http://images.apple.com/v/ipad-pro/d/images/overview/gallery_screen_5_medium.jpg" alt="image">
  <button onclick="alert('You clicked a button')"></button>
</div>
```

И стили кнопки:

```
.clickable-img button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 37.39%;    /* 212px / 567px */
  top: 8.94%;      /*  38px / 425px */
  width: 55.91%;   /* 317px / 567px */
  height: 31.29%;  /* 133px / 425px */
  background: #000;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s;
}
```

Обратите внимание на %. При позиционировании в px - верстка будет ломаться, если картинку вы будете вписывать в контейнер с ограниченной шириной (например, через `max-width: 100%;`. Поэтому лучше переводить величины px в %, делением на высоту и ширину картинки.

Comment: Да, всё отлично работает, большое спасибо!

Comment: Как сделать так, чтобы картинка располагалась по центру?